# iOS simulator crashes when using image_picker

Tags: flutter, dart

```
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final XFile? image =
                await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
          },
          child: Text('Add photo'),
        ),
```

As described in the image_picker example this should work when the button is clicked but the app just crashes without any debug info.

Answer (score 1):

From the Image Picker Docs:
Add the following keys to your Info.plist file, located in /ios/Runner/Info.plist:

`NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`- describe why your app needs permission for the photo library. This is called Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description in the visual editor.
`NSCameraUsageDescription` - describe why your app needs access to the camera. This is called Privacy - Camera Usage Description in the visual editor.
`NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` - describe why your app needs access to the microphone, if you intend to record videos. This is called Privacy - Microphone Usage Description in the visual editor.

If using Android Studio/ VS Code - goto ios/Runner/info.plist and add the following lines.

Note: You can add custom strings.

```
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string> App wants to access your camera</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string> App wants to access your gallery</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string> App wants to access your microphone</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the image_picker docs it says that when using the iOS 14+ simulator. However they fail to mention that the app will also crash. In order for you to use this in the simulator you need give access to the image gallery to add this to your info.plist:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>To chose a picture from the gallery</string>
```

Comment: In general, keep this incident in your mind when an app crashes after adding a dependency. It is most of the time caused by not adding the permissions.